# Can't configure pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, configure

When I compile pyQt on Windows 7 it returns an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "configure.py", line 32, in <module>
       import sipconfig
ImportError: No module named sipconfig
```

I have configured sip but the error still occurs. Can anyone help?

Comment: You configured sip, but did you also build and install it?

Comment: I Built sip but the command prompt threw an error when I ran the `make` and `make install` commands.

Comment: It returned the error `'make' is not recognised as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, the make command is `NMAKE`.

Comment: I don't have MS Visual Studio

Comment: Perhaps you don't have a C++ compiler at all?

Comment: What is a C++ Compiler, are they free?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps one of the [binary packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download/) would suit you. No need to compile.

Answer (score 9):

The same happened to me on OSX.

As @Janne Karila suggested, you need to [download](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) and build SIP first.
In the extracted sip source folder issue these commands in a terminal:

```
python configure.py
make
sudo make install
```

After that (in case it succeeds) you should be able to build PyQt in his folder using the same 3 commands.

Comment: I had the reported issue because I did `sudo make`. Thanks

Comment: I had to specify I was building with `mingw`: `python configure.py --platform win32-g++`

Answer (score 1):

When building sip, try using `sudo` so you can write the files to the `/System` directory:

```
sudo python configure.py
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I had same issue, then looked at the install directories and noticed files where not there, so I used `sudo` and successfully built it. Got PyQt built as well.

Comment: It is enough to use sudo for `make install` command only, if you need it to be installed in system dirs. Using sudo for configure and make is not a good idea because of changed files permissions, different env etc.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the sip from  here [download](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download). Extract the sip folder in the PyQt4 folder

```
cd sip-version
python configure.py
make
make install
```

From the same location and it will compile and save to `C:\Python` folder

Comment: You should at least mention we need to do `make`.