# Python: Install sip

Tags: python-2.7, build, module

I wanted to install the python module sip (version 4.17) according to the documentation on my Windows 7 machine:

- Download from the official page as described in the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html)
- Unzip the repository to the folder `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sip-4.17`
- Configure the package with the command `python.exe configure.py` in this folder
- Building the module `mingw32-make` fails.

Mingw's make returns the following error message:

```
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sip-4.17/sipgen'
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o main.o main.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o transform.o transform.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o gencode.o gencode.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o extracts.o extracts.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o export.o export.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o heap.o heap.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o parser.o parser.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o lexer.o lexer.c
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-subsystem,console -Wl,-s -o sip.exe main.o transform.o gencode.o extracts.o export.o heap.o parser.o lexer.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sip-4.17/sipgen'
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sip-4.17/siplib'
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o siplib.o siplib.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o apiversions.o apiversions.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o descriptors.o descriptors.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o qtlib.o qtlib.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o threads.o threads.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o objmap.o objmap.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o voidptr.o voidptr.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o array.o array.c
g++ -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -IC:\Python27\include -o bool.o bool.cpp
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -shared -Wl,-subsystem,console -Wl,-s -o sip.pyd siplib.o apiversions.o descriptors.o qtlib.o threads.o objmap.o voidptr.o array.o bool.o -LC:\Python27\libs -lpython27
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'sip.pyd' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sip.pyd] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sip-4.17/siplib'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no clue why it failed to compile the code saying `File format not recognized`. Is it the same mistake as in [g++ output: file not recognized: File format not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17126384/2062965)?
Thank you for your help in advance!

### Comment:

I followed the following questions too but I want to install it using the zip file - so I know what is installed.

- [Can't configure pyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11841962/2062965)
- [How to install SIP & PyQT on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32054021/2062965)

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure SIP? You need to choose a configuration option (see documentation in the docs file of the SIP archive). I got this to work once I chose --platform win32-g++.