# Python(x,y): MinGW installation - MWE

Tags: python, windows, mingw

#### Background

I reinstalled Python(x,y) on my Windows 7 machine. When I finished the installation I wanted to upgrade all packages using pip. But the mingw compiler gives some weird error messages. 
My last question could hopefully get resolved by this issue: [Python: Install sip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35018166/2062965)

Therefore I checked out [an example online](http://sebsauvage.net/python/mingw.html) that builds C code for Python using mingw. But it failed - that might be an indication that mingw is not working as intended. I have some details if this helps anything:

- `mingw32-make --version` 3.82.90
- `gcc --version` 4.8.1
- `python --version` 2.7.10

I configured Python (`C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg`) according to the [qutip installation guide](http://qutip.org/docs/3.1.0/installation.html#installation-on-windows) and https://docs.python.org/2/install/#location-and-names-of-config-files.

## Issue

I want to test my mingw installation since I cannot upgrade the Python packages with pip. Please give me some tested code to check if my installation is working properly together with Python.

Comment: This may help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34934865/5781248

Comment: What is `gendef`? I do not have it...

Comment: It is available here, http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/gendef/gendef-1.0.1346/ . `mingw-get install gendef` might work if *mingw-get* command exists.

Comment: The first one did not solve my pip problems. If you like, I can pastebin the messages.

Comment: Yes, better to put those error messages somewhere.

Comment: [Failed scipy upgrade](http://pastebin.com/t6Lz5XK1) - I have the impression that pip installs differently than the python(x,y) installer.