# How to install PyQt4 with Python 3.6.4 (Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH. )

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, mingw

I am having real trouble with installing PyQt4 package. I have read many documentations about this but still have not figured it out. So my first question is when I download the PyQt4 zip fail, where I have to extract it?

I have tried to extract it to the \Lib\site-packages and then from there run a PS and use the command "python configure-ng.py" then it gives me an error "Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH." Although I have the QT software installed.

I found that there is two qmake folders in my system. One located "Qt\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\templates\wizards\projects" and the other located "Qt\Tools\Preview\Qt Creator 4.5.0 rc1\share\qtcreator\templates\wizards\projects". I also tried to copy the "qmake" folder to the directory where the PyQt4 files are, but still nothing.

UPDATE: So I gave up trying to install with the configure-ng.py fail and started to try adding the package with configure.py. And then first I got an error "No module named 'sipconfig'".
I found over the internet that it is caused, cause SIP is not installed and you need to installid like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841962/cant-configure-pyqt) . Then I encountered a error "make is not recognized as an internal or external command python" So I installed MinGW C compiler. Now I f I run it C:\PATH\main.exe I get an error:

```
PS G:\Programmeerimine\uus\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4_gpl_win-4.12.1\sip 4.19.7> C:\MinGW\bin\make.exe
make[1]: Entering directory 'G:/Programmeerimine/uus/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4_gpl_win-4.12.1/sip-4.19.7/sipgen'
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o main.o main.c
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'G:/Programmeerimine/uus/Lib/site-
packages/PyQt4_gpl_win-4.12.1/sip-4.19.7/sipgen'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got help form another forum. The solution is described [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/87197/pyqt4-installation-process-error)